# Linker does not recognize format of compiled Rust file

Tags: rust, linker, linker-errors

I am writing an OS kernel in Rust, and have reached the stage of linking said kernel to a bootloader written in Assembly. The kernel (`kernel.rs`) compiles fine to `kernel.o` using `rustc` with the `x86_64-unknown-none` target.

The problem arises when I try to link this kernel to my bootloader. I attempt to link `kernel.o` to `kernel_enter.o` (compiled from a `.asm` file) with the `ld` linker:

```
ld -o "full_kernel.bin" -Ttext 0x1000 "kernel_enter.o" "kernel.o" --oformat binary
```

and received the the following error:

```
ld: kernel.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
```

I have tried to build with `x86_64-unknown-uefi`, and with `i686-unknown-uefi` and the `i386-elf-ld` linker.

I have also read of the possibility of writing custom targets with JSON. Knowing how to do that would probably solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share how you build `kernel.o`? It might possible rust is actually building it in `.elf` format instead of `.o`

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I used `rustc kernel.rs --target $(TARGET) -o kernel.o`.

Comment: Maybe try passing `--crate-type staticlib`, that should create a `.o` or `.a` (or maybe even `.rlib` but those are just `.a`, I believe)

Comment: Sorry, wrong flag, `--emit obj` should work however